# Semaphore values while customers are waiting during for a haircut in sleepy barber problem?

Tags: java, operating-system, deadlock, semaphore, starvation

I am working on using semaphore values in the sleepy barber problem. I am imagining a scenario in which a customer is already with the barber, and then 4 other customers enter the barber shop. The waiting room has a capacity of three seats. I want to know the semaphore values during this situation in whch the barber is already occupied.

I know that when a customer first comes in when the barber opens shop, I ended up with these semaphore values:

```
barber = 0
customer = 0
mutex = 1
```

Here is my pseudocode for this problem:

```
/* Counting semaphores - the integer value represents the initial count for the semaphores */

Semaphore customer = 0; /* Number of customer waiting for service */
Semaphore barber = 0; /* Number of barber waiting for students */
Semaphore mutex = 1; /* Mutual exclusion when accessing the waiting room */

int waiting = 0; /* Students waiting for turn with professor */

Barber() {
  while (TRUE) {
    wait (customer); /* Go to sleep if no customers */
    wait (mutex); /* Get access to waiting room */
    waiting--; /* Decrement number of waiting customers */
    signal (barber); /* Barber is ready */
    signal (mutex); /* Releasing waiting room */
    #GiveHaircut;
  }
}

Customer() {
  wait (mutex); /* Enter critical section, which is the waiting room */
  if (waiting < 3) { /* If there are free chairs in the waiting room */
    waiting++;
    signal (customer); /* Wake up barber if necessary */
    signal (mutex); /* Release access to count of waiting customers */
    wait (barber); /* Wait for barber if not available */
    #GetHaircut;
  } else {
    signal (mutex); /* Waiting area is full, leave without waiting */
  }
}
```

When I try to trace this code and a barber is already occupied, I keep getting `barber = -1`.

I am not sure if this is possible as a value and am just feeling very confused and would appreciate if someone could help me trace the pseudocode to find the semaphore values in this situation? I have only seen examples in which a customer comes in, but no other scenarios online. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if in you have one or multiple barbers in your scenario so I'll give you short pseudo-code drafts for both cases. 
In both of these cases we'll assume you have a 3 seat waiting room - which means you have a semaphore with max val of 3 and when customers come in they wait for a free spot and once it's their turn to get a haircut they signal there's now one seat free. For the seats 'resource' we'll have a semaphore called seatsAvailable.
Barber's only 'worry' is that he has customers so for him we'll introduce a semaphore called customersAvailable.

So, when you have a single barber all of your customers are using the same 'resouce' which is your single barber - so you need a mutex semaphore, we'll call it barberMutex.

**One barber scenario**

```
Semaphore barberMutex = 1
Semaphore customersAvailable = 0
Semaphore seatsAvailable = 3

Barber:
wait(customersAvailable) // wait for customers to show up
# doHaircut...
signal(barberMutex) // after one customer has been served, barber is free

Customer:
wait(seatsAvailable) // wait for an available seat
signal(customersAvailable) // once you've sat signal to you barber that there's customers waiting
wait(barberMutex) // wait if the barber is not free
signal(seatsAvailable) // once it's your turn, you go to barber and there is an open seat
# getHaircut
```

**Multiple barbers scenario**
For this scenario we have multiple barbers so we won't have a mutex but an semaphore with a val of n where n is number of barbers working in that shop (let's say 3 for our example and call that semaphore barbersAvailable).

```
Semaphore barbersAvailable = 3
Semaphore customersAvailable = 0
Semaphore seatsAvailable = 3

Barber:
wait(customersAvailable)
#doHaircut
*signal(barbersAvailable)*

Customer:
wait(seatsAvailable) // wait for an available seat
signal(customersAvailable) // once you've sat signal to you barber that there's customers waiting
*wait(barberAvailable)* // wait for one of the barbers to be free
signal(seatsAvailable) // once it's your turn, you go to barber and there is an open seat
# getHaircut
```

I'm always assuming **wait** busy waits for the resouce, and after obtaining it decreases the val for that semaphore, also **signal** increases the val for the semaphore.